# Java Spring - write to existing file in resource folder

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

I have a simple in-memory db in which I load users from XML file at app startup.
Now whenever someone registers I want to save that new user in this xml file.
My approach is to everytime get all the users, append new one and save to xml.
However, seems like nothing is written in file at time the new user registers.
I am aware that this approach is not save but this is for educational reason only.

This is my save to xml class

```
public class SaveXml {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void saveUserToXml (User newUser) {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Users.xml").getFile());
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

            List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
            //populate arraylist with all users;
            userRepository.findAll().forEach(usersList::add);
            usersList.add(newUser);

            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            String xmlContent = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(usersList);
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Xml file that is placed in resource folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <username>Tom</username>
        <password>123</password>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>Moc</username>
        <password>1234</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

Users class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Users {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<User> user;

    public Users(List<User> newUser) {
        this.user = newUser;
    }

    public List<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(List<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

User class

```
@Data
public class User
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //defining id as column name
    @Column
    private int id;
    //defining name as column name
    @Column
    private String username;
    //defining password column
    @Column
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: you never write `xmlContent` to the file? You simply create the XML string and then close the File.

Comment: cant believe my numbness

Comment: First, the `getFile()` method of URL **does not** return a valid file name.  Your code will eventually fail, when the program happens to reside in a directory containing characters (like space) which are not legal in URLs.  Second, if your program is running inside a .jar, a resource is not writable, period.  Treat your resource as *default data* and write the new file to a known location, like the user’s home directory.  Finally, never ever write an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, call `e.printStackTrace()`.  You want to know if the operation fails, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FileUtils` from Apache.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

```
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(
                    file,
                    xmlContent,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                    true // == append to end of file
            );
```

The JavaDoc of this method:

```
         /**
         * Writes a String to a file creating the file if it does not exist.
         *
         * @param file     the file to write
         * @param data     the content to write to the file
         * @param charset the charset to use, {@code null} means platform default
         * @param append   if {@code true}, then the String will be added to the
         *                 end of the file rather than overwriting
         * @throws IOException in case of an I/O error
         * @since 2.3
         */
```